# How can I use "apply" for custom function with 2 inputs

Tags: r, loops, apply, raster

I'm working in R with two multiband raster time-series (92 bands for each raster):

- One raster is a MODIS EVI
- The other raster is MODIS QA

Both rasters with same extent and bands.

I have to pass a custom function to EACH PIXEL (with 92 bands) that needs two inputs in a time-series object.

`function(input EVI, input QA)`

So, I'm doing a nested `for` loop to get a time series for a pixel over all bands:

```
for(i in 1:nrow...) {
       for(j in 1:ncol...) {
```

So in each iteration I am passing the custom function over a set of two pixel time series.

I know this is the worst way and all the people suggest `apply` instead of a nested loop but:

- I can't make an `apply` with two inputs for each pixel.

Somebody knows a way to avoid nested looping but passing my custom function?

Comment: I got reading the first part of your question ( before `apply` ) and was just thinking "Ooh that sounds painful." So what we're looking for here is a way to apply a function across series of pixels? Just want to make sure I know what your want here.

Comment: There's `mapply` that works almost like you want (it takes multiple list as inputs).  Another workaround is to do a triple argument function like `function(id, input EVI, input QA)` where you, in the function, extracts the info you want (`inputEVI[id]`).  I didn't write those solutions as answers because I'm not sure they're adaptable to rasters easily.  If you want more help, I suggest to make a reproducible example.  It doesn't have to be two enourmous 92 bands rasters, just something small to better understand your problem.